# Why is it difficult to construct the Ramond-Ramond sector in Berkovits' SFT?

Tags: string-field-theory

I've been trying to get familiar with string field theory (SFT) and I've stumbled upon the statement that the Ramond-Ramond (RR) sector of Nathan's SFT has not been constructed yet. Why is that?